# Как сделать такой внешний border-radius?

Tags: css, css3

Стоит задача сделать такой **border-radius**.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой `border-radius` у бургер меню? Идей нету.

У меня была только одна попытка `border-top-right-radius: 20px;` и то безуспешная.

Ключевой элемент `nav` все радиусы добавляйте туда.

Вот бургер меню

```js
$('.burger, .overlay').click(function(){
  $('.burger').toggleClass('clicked');
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('show');
  $('nav').toggleClass('show');
  $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*  БУРГЕР
========================================== */
.burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.burger span {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
}
.burger span, .burger span::before, .burger span::after {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: background-color, transform;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.burger span::before, .burger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.burger span::before {
  top: -9px;
}
.burger span::after {
  top: 9px;
}
.burger.clicked span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.burger.clicked span::before {
  transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}
.burger.clicked span::after {
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.burger.clicked span:before, .burger.clicked span:after {
  background-color: black;
}
.burger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*  NAV ключевое свойство для радиуса/ */
nav {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
nav.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
nav.show ul.main li {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 1.05s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
nav.show ul.main li:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: 1.35s;
}
nav.show .about, nav.show .social, nav.show ul.sub {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .85s;
}
@media (min-width: 667px) {
  nav {
    padding: 120px 90px 70px 90px;
  }
}
nav ul.main {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul.main li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(40px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul.main li:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
nav ul.main li a {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul.main li a span {
  color: #b7ac7f;
}
/*  ОВЕРЛЕЙ
========================================== */
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.overlay.show {
  opacity: 0.8;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <span></span>
</div>

<nav>
  <ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.menu.show {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.menu.show::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -46px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
.menu.show::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(-100% - 20px);
}
.menu.show .main::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 13px solid #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/br1e0hcz/12/